# can not view selector controls outside the clipping area in canvas (fabric.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, fabricjs

I used below code to clip area of canvas using fabric.js plugin

```
//set it as a canvas fix parent element
                        var shape = canvas.item(0);
                        canvas.remove(shape);
                        canvas.clipTo = function(ctx) {
                            shape.render(ctx);
                        };

                        canvas.renderAll();
```

But if I drag element outside of clipped area, controls get invisible. Need that controls to be visible throughout the canvas even if we drag element outside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `canvas.controlsAboveOverlay = true;` after the clipTo-function. It works not only with overlay-images but also with clipped objects.